# MathKernel.exe not being killed while running from .NET C#

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, .netlink

I am using Mathematica from .NET (C#) to compute the result based on some input, following is the code snippet of C#

```
 using (var mathKernel = new MathKernel())
    {                     
        mathKernel.Compute("PDF[NormalDistribution[-5, 3], x]");
        if (mathKernel.Result != null)
        {
            var response = mathKernel.Result.ToString();                        
        }
    }
```

above code is called after every minute, upon calling a process named "MathKernel.exe" is created every time, occupy approx. 100 MB of RAM and it does not exit after execution of above code.

[image: MathKerne.exe In Task Manager]

MathKernel instance is created in using block which is supposed to dispose after end of closing bracket.

Is there something which I am missing?

Comment: I can't comment on the .NET specific aspects, but generally, when using Mathematica through a MathLink/WSTP connection, it is preferable to re-use a single kernel instead of starting a new one for each computation. When you are done, you need to close the link to the kernel. How this is done with .NET I do not know, but in case you didn't check the docs yet, you should. Look in SystemFiles/Links/NETLink/Documentation.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Perhaps you can find some wisdom on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926869/do-you-need-to-dispose-of-objects-and-set-them-to-null) page regarding Dispose().